# What is daily summary?

Tags: support, timeline

I am a new contributor, and asked some questions recently. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61581323/how-to-commit-unversioned-directories-to-svn-repo-with-git-svn), I noticed the following in the timeline.

[image]

What is "daily summary"? Is it something automated, or do moderators make them?

If it is an automatic process, what may be the cause for the score decrease?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The system counts the number of upvotes and downvotes that the post received that day and aggregates them to provide a summary of all the voting that happened.

The score decrease means that there was one more downvote than upvote that day on that post, as score = upvotes - downvotes.

Once you get more rep the summary gets broken down into a [separate downvote count and upvote count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user), so I can see that there was one downvote that day on that post and no upvotes.

Comment: I thought every upvote and downvote would be visible as a separate entry in the timeline, containing info regarding who gave it and the reasons, comments etc. But I guess that would be impractical. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: voting is anonymous and there are various measures in place to keep it so, including this. If there were any comments on the post they would show in the timeline.